# Android: adding text on compound drawable image in textview

Tags: java, android, drawable

I am working on a text view which shows the number of selected items (from a multiple choice list) with the number having a circle around it. I thought to add the circle by using the setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (as I don't want to have 2 separate text views to achieve the desired look), but my question is if it's possible to somehow apply some text (in this case the number) over the circle image or if not, what would be the best solution for the label I have in mind?

I need to implement something looking like this:

[image]

What is your advice? Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: `my question is if it's possible to somehow apply some text (in this case the number)` **No**. A compound drawable is a... drawable. `I don't want to have 2 separate text views to achieve the desired look` but it's your **only choice**, unless you don't want to make your own custom view and override the `onDraw()` method

Comment: yes, you can use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` with a custom `Drawable` that draws the circle with the text inside, just make a class that extends `Drawable` class and override `draw` method

Comment: and if it is too much to extend `Drawable` class you can use `ShapeDrawable` with a custom `Shape` passed to `ShapeDrawable` constructor

Comment: Thanks @pskink, your suggestion is definitely to consider :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinearLayout for that instead of single TextView implement click of LinearLayout.

For XMl use this:-

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/line">

<TextView 
android:id="@+id/txtNumber"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/round_bg"/>

<TextView 
android:id="@+id/txtDropDown"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawable_right="@drawable/arrow_down"/>

</LinearLayout>
```